# Seeking mean and SD from multiple sample in R

Tags: r, sample, mean

I want to generate 25 normal samples from an normal distribution.  I'm looking to do this in a intelligent manner where I don't have all these samples as separate entities.

This is the code I have so far for that portion

```
data <- replicate(25, rnorm(100))
```

So far this is what as it generates 25 samples of 100. When extracting the mean and sd for data, obviously the values are for the entire data set.

So my question is how do I disaggregate this and determine `mean` and `sd` for each of the 25 samples?

Comment: along with doing this i want to run some maximum likelihood code on the data sample created. this is what i have so far:                      library("maxLik")

logLikFun <- function(param) {
mu <- param[1]
sigma <- param[2]
sum(dnorm(data, mean = mu, sd = sigma, log = TRUE))
}
mle <- maxLik(logLik = logLikFun, start = c(mu = 0, sigma = 1))

summary(mle)         but again having some problems extracting the mean and sd for each sample of the 25, i ammended the apply function to try to suit this but nothing has worked yet. any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nice alternative to `apply(x, 2, mean)` is `colMeans(x)`, but there's not such alternative for `apply(x, 2, sd)` :( But you can also get both the mean and the standard deviation in just one shot using apply function, let's do it:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- replicate(25, rnorm(100))

Stats <- t(apply(x, 2, function(x) c(Mean=mean(x), Sd=sd(x))))
Stats
              Mean        Sd
 [1,]  0.032514816 1.0413570
 [2,] -0.087483707 0.9041735
 [3,] -0.010368172 1.0170123
 [4,]  0.032936464 0.8761978
 [5,] -0.117830506 1.0199916
 [6,]  0.002363510 1.0633145
 [7,] -0.086747228 0.9755756
 [8,] -0.169291497 0.8830939
 [9,]  0.061457015 1.0377577
[10,]  0.084205039 1.1804565
[11,] -0.129164759 1.0080920
[12,]  0.039991367 0.9814254
[13,]  0.078980115 0.9719501
[14,] -0.148572682 0.9125126
[15,] -0.048566771 0.9562642
[16,]  0.006789862 1.0347380
[17,]  0.274102604 1.0212837
[18,] -0.113169899 0.9988576
[19,]  0.151418057 0.9830082
[20,] -0.164987838 0.9348188
[21,] -0.035644377 1.0214245
[22,] -0.041569005 1.0159495
[23,]  0.051384229 1.0944096
[24,]  0.073521001 0.9084400
[25,]  0.021893835 0.9438906
```

Comment: thanks guys, very helpful comments. Just an additional query, i want to get the sd of the mean of the 25 samples but R is returning NA for the typical sd(mean) command (im actually using xbar as the sample label). Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: along with doing this i want to run some maximum likelihood code on the data sample created. this is what i have so far: library("maxLik") logLikFun <- function(param) { mu <- param[1] sigma <- param[2] sum(dnorm(data, mean = mu, sd = sigma, log = TRUE)) } mle <- maxLik(logLik = logLikFun, start = c(mu = 0, sigma = 1)) summary(mle) but again having some problems extracting the mean and sd for each sample of the 25, i ammended the apply function to try to suit this but nothing has worked yet. any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply` to sweep out the summaries.

```
set.seed(42)
x <- replicate(25, rnorm(100))
```

Since your data is a column-wise matrix, you need to `apply` your function to the second dimension.

```
apply(x, 2, mean)
 [1]  0.032514816 -0.087483707 -0.010368172  0.032936464
 [5] -0.117830506  0.002363510 -0.086747228 -0.169291497
 [9]  0.061457015  0.084205039 -0.129164759  0.039991367
[13]  0.078980115 -0.148572682 -0.048566771  0.006789862
[17]  0.274102604 -0.113169899  0.151418057 -0.164987838
[21] -0.035644377 -0.041569005  0.051384229  0.073521001
[25]  0.021893835


apply(x, 2, sd)
 [1] 1.0413570 0.9041735 1.0170123 0.8761978 1.0199916
 [6] 1.0633145 0.9755756 0.8830939 1.0377577 1.1804565
[11] 1.0080920 0.9814254 0.9719501 0.9125126 0.9562642
[16] 1.0347380 1.0212837 0.9988576 0.9830082 0.9348188
[21] 1.0214245 1.0159495 1.0944096 0.9084400 0.9438906
```

Comment: thanks guys, very helpful comments.  Just an additional query, i want to get the sd of the mean of the 25 samples but R is returning NA for the typical sd(mean) command (im actually using xbar as the sample label). Any ideas to solve this?